# Angular-slick will not go to next slide

Tags: slick.js

I am stuck trying to figure out why my angular-slick carousel will not navigate to the next slide:

To reproduce the issue go to:
http://a76.f6e.myftpupload.com/home-designs/#/model/towns/th_23_1/aquamarine/a

(Login with "indigo", make sure your screen is reduced to mobile dimensions)

Try to click on the dots of the floor plans outlines carousel  (or on your phone swipe to the right).  The carousel does not progress to the next slide.
When I put an event handler beforeChange in the code with a console.log, I see that the carousel is calling the action, but the carousel doesn't progress to the next slide.  I have tried to comment all the enhancements to the css I have made, but nothing seems to work.

Does anyone have any idea what is going on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue.  It was because I had two stacked carousels and was using opacity:0 without visibility : hidden so the user couldn't click on the carousel below...

Always good to step away from the problem and look at from fresh eyes ;)